# DotNetNuke > CreateUser Programatically Throws Error System.Typeinitializationexception

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, vb.net-to-c#

This one has eaten up my time today. I'm upgrading a web app that was originally built off an old version of DotNetNuke. The legacy app creates a user in DNN which I would think would be pretty straight forward. I converted the original code from VB.net to c#, updated to the latest DNN Core and DNN Infrastructure Nuget packages. When I run my code, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in DotNetNuke.dll but was not handled in user code

I've looked at several sets of example code online for creating users in DotNetNuke, and my code seems to follow these fairly closely (see below). Each property on the dnnUser object seems to get properly filled in when I step through the code, but it always fails with the above error when it hits the line to execute Membership.CreateUserStatus. Any thoughts as to what is going on here, or how I might resolve this?

```
    public myUser SaveUser(myUser ngUser)
    {

    DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo dnnUser = new DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo();
        dnnUser.Email = ngUser.Email;
        dnnUser.Username = ngUser.Username;
        dnnUser.DisplayName = ngUser.FirstName + " " + ngUser.LastName;
        dnnUser.FirstName = ngUser.FirstName;
        dnnUser.LastName = ngUser.LastName;
        dnnUser.PortalID = 0;
        dnnUser.Membership.Password = ngUser.Password;
        dnnUser.Membership.Approved = true;
        dnnUser.Membership.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

        if (ngUser.UserID == 0)
        {
            DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserCreateStatus status = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.CreateUser(ref dnnUser);

            if (status == DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.UserCreateStatus.Success)
            {
```

Comment: One other thing that may be coming into play here. The original app was doing the user creation within the instance of DNN. This new app is creating users outside of DNN.

Comment: Tested your snippet. It works just fine. The problem is not in there.

Comment: I've tested it many, many, many times only to get the same error, but it is good to know that the block looks solid. Anywhere else you can think of that might be causing issues? I've also tried to replace each of those ngUser properties with static strings to the same result. I'm starting to run out of places to look at this point.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. But `TypeInitializationException` error is not DNN specific, maybe the clue is in there.